# Belgian Styles brewed in Seattle?

Tags: style, trappist

Suggestions on breweries that brew Belgian styles within Seattle city limits?

Answer (score 2):

[Lantern Brewing](https://www.lanternbrewing.com)

> Lantern Brewing is a family-owned microbrewery in the Greenwood neighborhood of Seattle, Washington.  We focus on creating unhurried, honest beer following the brewing traditions of Belgium and Northern France.